# Убить процесс запущенный от sudo Python

Tags: python

Таким образом у меня запускается процесс

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['sudo','openvpn', '--auth-nocache', '--config', path], preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)
```

убиваю я его так

```
pgid = str(os.getpgid(process.pid))
print(pgid)
subprocess.check_output("sudo kill {}".format(pgid))
```

Появляется такая ошибка

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sudo kill 6888': 'sudo kill 6888'
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `POSIX` системах, если командная строка содержит аргументы, она должна быть задана в виде списка

```
subprocess.check_output(['sudo', 'kill', str(pgid)])
```

Также можно указать параметр `shell=True`, и тогда команда будет запущена под шелом со всеми вытекающими.

```
subprocess.check_output("sudo kill {}".format(pgid), shell=True)
```

Comment: Не только в posix.

Comment: @Qwertiy в документации сказано только про `POSIX`. Возможно в каких-то системах так же, но в `Windows` (по крайней мере, в `Windows 7`) это не обязательно `subprocess.check_output('cmd /c dir')`

Comment: Какая-то питонная магия. Проверил - действительно работает. Но в nodejs методы разнесены - один для выполнения команды, другой - программы. И второй не запускает команду - ENOENT. И .net тоже не работало, насколько я помню.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну `check_output` тоже не запустит команду шела без `shell=True`, если речь об этом. `subprocess.check_output('dir')` выдаст ошибку.

Comment: Нет, речь про `cmd /c dir` единственным параметром без деление на программу `cmd` и аргументы `/c dir`.

Comment: @Qwertiy winapi функцию `CreateProcess` можно запустить так `CreateProcess("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "/c dir", ...)` или так `CreateProcess(NULL, "cmd /c dir", ...)`. В первом случае аргументы отдельно и первый аргумент должен быть путем до файла. `check_output` по умолчанию использует второй вариант, но можно указать первый аргумент отдельно `subprocess.check_output('/c dir', executable=r'c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe')`.

Comment: Ну, видимо, он его намеренно использует?

Comment: @Qwertiy Видимо так :)

Comment: На мой взгляд, смахивает на дыру в безопасности, если надо без параметров запустить? Хотя, может и нет - мы ж и так уже что-то запускаем...

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну вообще, в документации сказано, что если имя содержит пробел, его надо брать в кавычки `"\"программа с пробелом\" аргументы"`, но у меня работает и `"программа с пробелом аргументы"` :). Так что да, не особо безопасно.